# What techniques require mutable texture storage

Tags: opengl, textures

I have just been reading up on the advantages of immutable texture storage. Whilst I understand that, using mutable storage, I would be able to resize the texture storage on demand, I don't see why I would want to.

What techniques make use of mutable texture storage in a way that is not possible or poorly performing in immutable texture storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to quote from the ARB's discussions in the [ARB_texture_storage extension](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/texture_storage.txt). Note that these are the questions and discussions *from the IHVs* who implement OpenGL, people who know their GPUs better than most of us:

> 4: Should use of these entry-points make the metadata (format and dimensions) immutable?
>
> RESOLVED: Yes.
>
> DISCUSSION: The benefits of knowing metadata can't change will probably outweigh the extra cost of checking the TEXTURE_IMMUTABLE_FORMAT flag on each texture specification call.
>
> 5: Should it be legal to completely replace the texture using a new call to TexStorage*?
>
> RESOLVED. It will not be allowed.
>
> DISCUSSION: This is useful to invalidate all levels of a texture. Allowing the metadata to be changed here seems easier than trying to define a portable definition of what it means to change the metadata (e.g. what if you used an unsized internal format the first time and the corresponding sized internal format the second time, or vice-versa)?
>
> However, while this is largely similar to deleting the old texture object and replacing it with a new one, it does lose some of the advantages of immutability. Specifically, because doing so does not reset bindings, it doesn't allow a migration path to an API that validates the texture format at bind time.
>
> 6: Should it be legal to use TexImage* after TexStorage* if it doesn't affect the metadata?
>
> RESOLVED: No.
>
> DISCUSSION: A potential use case is to allow a single level of a texture to be invalidated using a NULL pointer. However, as noted above it is non-trivial to determine what constitutes a change.

Allow me to put it another way: if the ARB thought in-situ texture modification was a good idea, they wouldn't have had `glTexStorage` *explicitly forbid it*.

Answer (score 2):

There are several cases where mutable textures are useful. Here are a few off the top of my head.

1. In a GPGPU application, it is very often the case that input data is not fully gridded, but sparse. In such cases I've had to  waste memory - mutable textures allow resizing to prevent this.
2. Impostor/billboard LOD - no need to allocate a large texture when something small will do
3. Data-dependent mathematical operations with textures, say convolution based on a computed mask/size
4. Caching pieces of "costly" rendered output for compositing. Dynamic resizing of these storage textures save precious GPU memory.

And many more I'm probably missing, but I hope you get the gist.

Comment: -1: No. Just... just no. If you ever need to "resize" a texture, you can just destroy it and create a new one of an appropriate size. There is absolutely no reason to do this in-situ within a texture object

Comment: Cheers both of you, it is good to know that people do use these features even if there may be a case for not doing so. @Nicol: Was it just the resizing that was an issue or do you find the delete&resize fast enough for all your needs?

Comment: @NicolBolas Allocating textures is a driver call. Resizing a texture can be a much simpler operation inside the driver than allocating a new texture, hence faster. My own real experience corroborates the statement here (http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/156246-glGenTextures-DeleteTextures-performance) *This way, if you could reuse the same amount of memory (say the texture is the same format and same size), then it is much more efficient to not deallocate the texture*. I also take it there's a reason this made it into the OpenGL spec. Thanks for your opinion,

Comment: @ananthonline: "*if you could reuse the same amount of memory*" Then you wouldn't need to call `glTexImage` at all. You'd [use `glInvalidateTexImage`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage#Invalidation). Which is perfectly legitimate on immutable textures.

Comment: @ananthonline: There is no "before mutable textures" because mutable textures in OpenGL are not *new*. Textures have been mutable since ARB_texture_objects back in GL 1.1.